# Why use a Groovy shell script over Bash (when memory footprint is important)?

Tags: linux, bash, groovy

I've got a Bash script (50 lines of code) that requires a bit of hacking due to limitations of bash. So someone said: "hey, use a better language than bash for that!"

So, I looked at Groovy (Groovy/Grails is next up on my to-learn list, so maybe this is a good time). I can do more complex shell scripts, so this might be a perfect fit.

But when I run even a simple Groovy script (`while(true){...}`) the memory consumption of the Java process is 123M, ouch, I've got about 10 such scripts to run (all bash based now) on a box with 650M of memory. The equivalent stand-alone bash script runs in around 1.5M of memory.

So is this a case of:

- I'm a newbie doing something wrong, 123M memory footprint is not necessary?
- Groovy isn't a good fit here? Perhaps Python or Perl are more memory conscious?
- bash is a good option, even for its shortcomings, when a small footprint is important?

Comment: Groovy isn't a good fit because it's on the JVM.  Similarly, you wouldn't choose Jython for scripting unless you had some *really* good reason why you couldn't use CPython.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what you are doing and what limitation you are hitting. Maybe there is a way around that limitation so you don't have to pick another language or maybe you could get advised which particular language is most suitable/used for your problem domain.

Comment: I need to read from both stdin and a socket and have both threads access a shared hashtable (assoc. array in bash). The app is super simple, read names from socket, add to hashtable, read from stdin respond t/f if in hash table. The shared variable is a problem in bash due to subshells. My interim solution in bash is to read values from the socket and store them in a file (locking as necessary). Each time (or max once/30sec) a request comes in on stdin to check the hash it'll process the values in the file, adding them to the hashtable. The delayed update present in this case is no issue.

Comment: @David: Either of perl, python or ruby are well suited for that kind of thing. Perl is more likely to exist even on obscure old unices, but python is more modern, available on any non-obscure unix as well and comes with more comprehensive standard library.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If memory is limited like that, then any language running on the JVM will be at a disadvantage. And Groovy is such a language.

Other languages like Python or Perl have a leaner runtime and require less memory for simple scripts (my guess is that Python is still a bit leaner than Perl, but I can't back that up with numbers).

In my opinion Python is a nice step-up from bash scripts, providing much nicer features while still being lean enough to be used in common scripts.

bash itself is a nice scripting language with a reasonable memory requirement. If memory footprint is **really** important, than another POSIX-compliant shell (such as [dash](http://%20or%20ash)) might be a reasonable replacement. Note that many, but not all features of `bash` are present in modern POSIX-compliant Shells.

Comment: I'd also add Ruby into the list.  I love Python, but some things (calling shell commands and parsing the output, regexes) are just more difficult than necessary.  Ruby, otoh, is a more readable Perl, which makes it fantastic for little sysadmin scripts.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Ruby, but seeing it described as "a more readable Perl" **really** makes me want to learn it!

Comment: @Joachim: Ruby looks nice, but seeing the problems Linux distributors have with them (lack of backward compatibility, unwillingness to support system-wide library installations) I just don't trust it. That's a community issue, not a language one (similar attitude exists in Java community).

Comment: Isn't there a way to compile JVM stuff to binary? I thought I'd heard of something like that.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a formula:

- Use Bash for scripts that merely poke and tickle other programs.
- Avoid Perl unless you fancy yourself as an archaic die-hard hacker.
- Use Python or Ruby for scripts that automate lightweight tasks.
- Use Groovy or Scala for scripts that automate heavy-duty tasks.

Groovy and Scala are overkill for trivial tasks, but a godsend for bulldozer situations -- serious scripts make the JVM look pretty thrifty.

Answer (score 8):

When you launch and application that runs on a JVM you should be able to configure such things as the heap size and permgen space which should affect the memory footprint.  If you need to write in Java or Groovy or Jython or JRuby or Scala, then look for how this can be set for your application.

Yes, the JVM-based languages are known for memory consumption, such as the 8-byte overhead for objects and the need for padding that makes Integer objects require a lot more memory than you might think (look this up somewhere :-)).  However the JVM offers a lot of advantages: most JVMs have been highly tuned and optimized over the last 15 years by really smart people (can you write a garbage collector *that* good?).  And the Java platform is just huge.  It has everything.

Are your 10 scripts long-running and need to be memory-resident all at the same time?  Or are they quick-running?  Since you have already written them in Bash, it sounds like you have no need for the rich Java platform. Are you just moving files around, and cutting and grepping and awking and sedding?

Aas a rule of thumb I like Bash for small scripts, but once I get to the point where I have a loops or two and a couple of variables (basically anything involving logic other than an if statement), Ruby and Python start looking so much easier to read and maintain.  Groovy isn't necessarily a bad choice (although the other languages are more popular).  But as far as memory footprint issues go, you should take the time to try and tune your JVM-based applications and make some measurements.  In your situation, it might not matter much.  Perhaps JVM startup time plays a factor?  A lot depends on your specific situation.

Comment: I wouldn't call JVM garbage collector *that* good as it's part of the memory inefficiency problems of JVM, mainly because it still partly relies on manually setting the limits where other VMs (like .Net) adapt to the actual memory load fully automatically. And note, that JVM would really kick ass if it wasn't this memory hungry, because small memory footprint improves cache efficiency and that has significant impact on performance.

Comment: Very good point, Jan +1. Fifteen years of tuning by really smart people doesn't necessarily make something the best VM in the world (and you rightly point out a limitation).  It still beats what most individual programmers can build on their own (which was the point I was _trying_ to get across), and is "good enough" for many applications.

Answer (score 4):

Java in general has issues when you want to run a quickie on the command line. I have had a lot of success using (and extending) a tool called [Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/index.html). It basically runs one instance of a JVM and uses a native client to pipe scripts or basic commands to the server for evaluation, and the output streams are converted to command line standard output. The results are fairly impressive.

Also see this [mail post](http://www.mail-archive.com/jvm-languages@googlegroups.com/msg00126.html). To quote:

> Here's a sample of JRuby startup time on OS X Java 6, first normal and
>   then with ng:
>
> normal:
>
> ~/NetBeansProjects/jruby $ time jruby -e "puts 'hello'" hello
>
> real    0m1.944s user    0m1.511s sys     0m0.138s
>
> nailgun:
>
> ~/NetBeansProjects/jruby $ time jruby -e "puts 'hello'" hello
>
> real    0m0.103s user    0m0.006s sys     0m0.009s

Comment: In the same vein, there's also the Groovy-specific GroovyServ - http://kobo.github.com/groovyserv/

Answer (score 1):

As you said use python or perl, for such things they have a much lower memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that "groovy" is just a wrapper script that starts "java -cp groovy.jar:$CLASSPATH" or something similar. That means you should check if there are JVM flags that affect the preallocated memory and change them accordingly.
Also do those scritps call each other? If so try to make them groovy classes instead and try to run them all in the same VM.